# Why is "a.template foo<0>();" allowed even though "a.foo<0>();" is enough?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, standards, member-functions

```
struct A
{
    template<int>
    void foo()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo<0>(); // ok
    a.template foo<0>(); // also ok
}
```

Obviously, `a.foo<0>();` is more concise, intuitive, and expressive than `a.template foo<0>();`.

**Why does C++ allow `a.template foo<0>();` even though `a.foo<0>();` is enough?**

Comment: Because in some situations `a.template foo<0>` is required, so why not allow it everywhere?

Comment: `template<typename T> void do_stuff() { T a; a.template foo<0>(); } ... do_stuff<A>();`

Comment: Not allowing it here would require more complexity in the language grammar.

Comment: There was a time when it wasn't allowed, matter of fact. C++11 relaxed the requirement to simplify the grammar. Try it with `-std=c++03 -pedantic-errors` and you'll have your compiler complain at you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes, inside a template, you need to write `a.template foo<0>()` instead of `a.foo<0>()`.

@melpomene gave this great example in the comments:

```
template<typename T>
void do_stuff() {
  T a;
  a.template foo<0>();
}
do_stuff<A>();
```

---

- **In C++03**, `a.template foo<0>()` should not be used in your current situation.

`g++` would output the following warning when compiling your code:

> warning: 'template' keyword outside of a template [-Wc++11-extensions]

- **In C++11**, the grammar has been simplified by allowing the use of the `a.template foo<0>()` syntax everywhere.